# Why is the 2nd step in two-step authentication not a single click?

Tags: authentication, google, multi-factor

### The case

I'm using Google 2-Step Verification.

### The question

Why does Google use a code as second step? Why not just an android app where you can click "It's me"?

Comment: Nobody can say for sure (except Google themselves), but it is worth noting that the app-based 2-Step Verification used by Google is built on an open standard. Because of that implementation choice, anybody can write an app that follows the same open standard and allows for users to import and use their Authenticator seed in the exact same way they do in the official app. If it was a "click-to-authorize" model, Google would have to provide an additional API into their systems which would by nature increase the attack surface in order to enable a feature that's supposed to *enhance* security.

Comment: If two or more people try accessing the same account at the same time, and only one of those users is legitimate, it wouldn't be possible for the app to know which sign in attempt it should verify.

Comment: @Scott if someone is able to fake a "it's me" notification, that means he have stolen the original secret. He might as well still the your MFA code

Comment: the obvious answer: The google authenticator app works when the phone doesn't have signal. It still gives you a code you can enter on the site. A button click would have to communicate to the server somehow.

Comment: @Iszi Why is this the standard? Why making things complicated for the user?

Comment: @Jay You are right about places without wireless connectivity. But I am guessing that most of the users that are aware of the importance of MFA have connectivity most of the time. Might be wrong here.

Comment: @Michael As I said earlier, and also what Jay said: Using the TOTP standard allows Google to provide an MFA mechanism without requiring the Authenticator to have connectivity, and also prevents them from having to add to their attack surface. With the "it's me" button, the Authenticator would have to be online, and Google's servers would have another attack vector exposed by way of the API used by that app.

Comment: Well. They actually did it http://venturebeat.com/2015/12/22/google-is-testing-signing-into-accounts-using-just-your-phone-no-password-required/

Answer (score 3):

If two or more people try accessing the same account at the same time, and only one of those users is legitimate, it wouldn't be possible for the app to know which sign in attempt it should verify, without the user identifying their particular attempt in some way.

As such it makes sense for the user to apply a code directly to their session. Also notable is that the codes are generated offline, based on a secret and device time. Using an "It's me" button would require an intermediary server through which the web app and the mobile app confirm the authentication request. This adds expense to the app, and introduces dependencies, a point of failure and potential point of vulnerability.

> @Scott if someone is able to fake a "it's me" notification, that means he have stolen the original secret. He might as well still the your MFA code

Imagine you are signing into your Google account, and a hacker is also attempting to sign in to your Google account. Both of you are at the MFA stage. Only you have the MFA device.

You press your "It's me" button to authenticate ... Which of the 2 pending sessions does that authenticate? The "It's me" idea then only works if you select the correct session. In which case a code is simpler and safer.

> In any case, the "that's me" notification can be a response to a challenge sent by the authentication server on your session. In which case you will be notified if an attacker attempted to log in. Any idea why that wouldn't work?

I can see what you are getting at with the device being notified of the attempt, and then you just confirm it with the app. It's not an unfeasible design. I guess ultimately it comes down to pros and cons:

Your suggested method:

- Intermediate server(s) required. To send notifications, to authenticate devices and session
- Servers require maintenance, cost money to run, can themselves be hacked, can fail / or be unreachable.
- The web app requires to talk to the MFA verification server.
- Only works online.
- Potentially more security holes and complexity.

The current code method:

- Free
- Works offline
- No servers required
- Open standard

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Scott! Usually it would be very difficult for the attacker to guess when I log in. In any case, the "that's me" notification can be a response to a challenge sent by the authentication server on your session. In which case you will be notified if an attacker attempted to log in. Any idea why that wouldn't work?

Comment: BTW, in any case of more than one session at the same time, I'd use some kind of alert and another layer of verification.

Comment: @Michael Yeah I get now what you are doing with the server notifying the MFA device of sessions, rather than blindly authenticating the last session. It boils down to complexity and cost. If users have to start choosing and identifying their sessions from potential hackers, through an alert or further verification, a slip of the finger, or muscle memory could let the hacker in. It's difficult too to standardise these extra steps. But you can't easily give the hacker your MFA code. MFA codes win because they are simple and cost almost nothing to implement.

Comment: Technically, you will have authentication servers in any case. So that the problem is at the same order of complexity. You are correct that each authentication requires only a single transaction in the code based 2-step authentication.

You forgot what might be a great deal breaker for an average user - the complexity of user experience of both methods.

The web app has to talk to the MFA server in any case, only much less frequently.

Free and open standard are minor reason in the long term, because you can make an open standard out of any simple idea and that way it will be for free.

Comment: I'd go with the online/offline concern and the number of transactions required. Those 2 against user experience.

Comment: @Michael True, the web app has to talk to the MFA server in any case. But it's all done through the same application that everyone's already using to log in anyway. With an "it's me" button, you need another application entirely on that server (or another server) that's listening for inbound connections. Hence, your attack surface (never mind the complexity of the system in general) is expanded.

Comment: I think the offline aspect of the codes is the most important part of this answer. Just because your computer has internet access doesn't mean your phone does; for example, you could be traveling abroad and not have cell service, and be accessing your account at a public computer terminal with wired internet access and no available WiFi.